# Cookies para almacenar valores Javascript

Tags: javascript, web

Quisiera que me ayuden con un problema. Lo que quiero es utilizar `cookies` para almacenar un valor este es el código

```
document.cookie="bandera=0;";

$(document).ready(function(){

var lascookies = document.cookie;
alert(lascookies);

$("#btn2").click(function() {
    document.cookie = "bandera=1;";
    $('#pum-55').hide();
    });
});
```

Con esto al cargar la página creo una `cookie` de nombre bandera y un valor 0, ahora cuando presiono el botón `btn2` quiero cambiar el valor de la `cookie` por valor 1.

Pero cuando vuelvo a recargar la página bandera vuelve a estar con valor 0.
Alguien me podría ayudar para que se mantenga ese valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia tu codigo por el siguiente

```
// Si la cookie no existe, la creas dandole el valor de cero
    if( !document.cookie == "bandera=0;" ){
       document.cookie = "bandera=0;";
    }


$(document).ready(function(){

var lascookies = document.cookie;
alert(lascookies);

$("#btn2").click(function() {
    document.cookie = "bandera=1;";
    $('#pum-55').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Muchisismas Gracias Jesus, tu respuesta me funcionó.
Sólo te hizo falta un "=" en  if( !document.cookie = "bandera=0;" ), no?

Comment: tienes razon, se me paso

Comment: No te precoupes, aún así me ayudaste mucho. Gracias man ;)
Te daria votos, pero mi reputación no me lo permite :'(

Comment: yo lo hago por ti soldado :D